# What does InMemoryColumnarTableScan do?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run a Spark SQL query and head to the Spark UI DAG visualization, the first step that is shown is called InMemoryColumnarTableScan.

Is my data loaded from disk every time I run a query?

If not, what does this step do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name suggests, the [InMemoryColumnarTableScan class](https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/refs/heads/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/columnar/InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala) contains methods which look at a table stored in memory using columnar compression techniques.

It's used to gather, cache, and provide statistics on the data stored within an in-memory table for more efficient querying of the table.

So the engine calls it first to figure out the best way to run your query against the RDD.

It doesn't have anything to do with your actual data load.